# Word for "multiple effects apply."

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm designing a game where, when players perform spcial game actions, their die rolls can receive bonuses. For instance, if you roll a 4 and have a +1 bonus, your final result is 5.

Now, some of these bonuses stack while others do not. Whether a bonus stacks depends on the effect that supplied the bonus.

By "stack," I mean "multiple bonuses combine into a larger bonus." If a player gets a +1 stacking bonus, a +1 stacking bonus, a +3 non-stacking bonus, and a +3 non-stacking bonus, the two +1 bonuses combine into a +2 bonus. The player is allowed to apply this combined bonus and **one** non-stacking bonus to his roll. In this case, he would increase his roll by +5 in total.

I don't think "stacking" is a very good word for this, however, so I'm looking for another word that can describe the bonuses that combine.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "Stacking" is the term used in all the RPGs I have played; I see no reason to avoid a term which is so widely understood in exactly the sense you describe.

Answer (score 2):

[Cumulative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cumulative):

1. Increasing or becoming better or worse over time through a series of additions
2. Including or adding together all of the things that came before

[Merriam-Webster]

As an example, in [Paizo Pathfinder RPG](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/gettingStarted.html)'s Getting Started page you can read:

> Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of the same type are not cumulative (do not "stack")—only the greater bonus granted applies.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a *compound* bonus with a *cumulative* value - compound in this case referring to "a combination of things", and *cumulative* referring to "something which develops from a sequence of additions".